# which of two indexes be used to evaluate this query in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, oracle11g, oracle10g

I got confused when learning indexes concept,

for ex: I have this simple query

```
select productId,productName from product where productId='11107' and productName='Watch';
```

and product is very large table,  productId and productName are two   attributes of product table and 11107 and Watch are two values.

I consider primary index on productId and  a secondary index on productName   assuming that 1000 records satisfy condition
   productId='11107' and 50 records satisfy condition productName='Watch' and  each datapage can store 100 records
   and the cost of a random IO is 10 times of that of a sequential I/O.

now which of two indexes be used to evaluate this query?

solution:

As per my understanding it should be primary index because the primary index    attribute "productId" returns multiple records say 1000 here, 
   when compared to seconday index attribute "productName" which returns only 50 records.

Also as each datapage stores 100 records then for primary index we need 10 pages and for secondary index 1 page.

As the table ""product" is very large so only less records say 50 satisfies  condition for sequential access(records are scanned one at a time).

is my evaluation correct or anything needs to be added. any suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for the question. Have you tested it yourself to see what actually happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things will be considered while evaluating best execution plan by Oracle.

1. Type of Index (unique, normal etc)
2. Below statistics from dba_indexes view

   LEAF_BLOCKS
   DISTINCT_KEYS
   CLUSTERING_FACTOR
   NUM_ROWS

For example, for equal condition Oracle gives lesser cost for the index for which DISTINCT_KEYS closer to NUM_ROWS

In your case, assuming both are normal indexes and all statistics are current - index which have more distinct keys might be preferred over the other.

Comment: so primary index should be used to evaluate query? what about the cost? which is more costlier?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it seems like your basic logic is backwards.  You seem to be saying that the primary index will be used because it will return more rows, which is the opposite of the basic rule of thumb - the more selective index is generally preferred.

However, another potential flaw in your logic is here:

> as each datapage stores 100 records then for primary index we need 10
>   pages and for secondary index 1 page

You should say "between 10 and 1000" and "between 1 and 50".  Just because *n* records can fit into a single "datapage" (or block, in Oracle terminology) does not mean that any *n* records you are looking for will actually be in the same block.  In your example, 10 blocks is the minimum to hold 1000 rows; but it is possible that the 1000 rows for the given productId are actually in 1000 different blocks.  (Assuming that the table is at least 1000 blocks in size.)

The question is not really about how many *rows* each index would return ("row selectivity"), but how many different *blocks* those rows are in ("block selectivity).  The optimizer uses the CLUSTERING_FACTOR value for each index to estimate how closely row and block selectivity match up with one another; low clustering factor generally means better block selectivity.

Going a bit beyond the scope of your question, it is also entirely possible that the optimizer would use neither index, or both.

At some point, the effort required to scan the index (which also requires I/O) then read the corresponding table blocks can be more than the effort required to simply read the entire table.  Again, CLUSTERING_FACTOR and other statistics figure into this decision.

In some cases, including your example, it is also possible that the optimizer will choose to do scans on both indexes and join the resulting index entries by the ROWID values, without ever accessing the table blocks at all.  This is possible because the query only uses the columns that are in the indexes; if you added another column to your select list, the query would have to read the table blocks to get that data.